# Conformal map from lower half plane to exterior of unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I need to find linear fractional transformation that transforms lower half plane to exterior of unit circle. I know that can be done by choosing three points and its images, but I can't figure out what points to choose.

Comment: Can you map the lower half-plane (conformally) to the unit disk? Then, what Möbius transformation switches interior and exterior of the unit circle?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer, you mean the inverse mapping? I can firstly rotate it by 180 degrees and I know Möbius transformation to unit disk.

Comment: If by "inverse mapping" you mean $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$, yes.